# Exception handler not being invoked

Tags: c#, exception

Running the really simple program below I'd expect 'FILTER REACHED' to execute when I click button1, but it doesn't get hit (neither with nor without debugger attached). Any ideas ... ?

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter += Dispatcher_UnhandledExceptionFilter;
                doer();
            }).Start();
    }
    void Dispatcher_UnhandledExceptionFilter(
        object sender,
        DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FILTER REACHED");
    }


    private void doer()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This looks a bit like C# to me. In any case you should tag this question with the language that you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on `Dispatcher` (found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexceptionfilter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) it looks like the filter function will only be used if an uncaught exception is raised from the `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` methods on the `Dispatcher`.

So what happens if you replace `doer()` with `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(doer)` (or similar) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method (doer) from a thread which is not the dispatcher thread.. you have to invoke the method using Dispatcher in order to catch the exception for filtering.

```
 new Thread(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter += Dispatcher_UnhandledExceptionFilter;
                 Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>doer()));
            }).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
    new Thread(() =>
    {
       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledExceptionFilter += Dispatcher_UnhandledExceptionFilter;
       Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new ThreadStart(delegate
       {
           doer();
       }));
    }).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) instead?